# Wit.ai Integration with Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, integration, bots, messenger, wit.ai

Hi I'm trying to integrate the Messenger Bot that I created using Node.js with Wit.ai based on https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit so my code is pretty much similar to this.

I've been reading the documentation but I'm really having a hard time understanding how the integration works as well as executing it. Can someone provide a step-by-step guide or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I would post the link here but as per stackoverflow guidelines, use the advanced search operator on Google and type **"wit.ai site:chatbotsmagazine.com"** They have some solid posts on how to set it up and integrate with different services